# why can't I convert a field in sql server from not null to null

Tags: sql-server

I have a db table that previously was not null (so every record had a value). I now want to make it nullable so its optional but it seems like SQL won't let you do this without deleting and recreating the table.

Why would it have this restriction if no data will be affected as I am going to a more lenient model (not a stricter one)?

Comment: Are you attempting to do this using a script, or through Management Studio's table designer? The table designer (in 2008 at least) doesn't let you do this, although it's perfectly possible using a script.

Comment: @ Jon Seigel - why does table designer block you ??

Comment: I have no idea. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name data_type NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the table designer from blocking you: Tools | Options | Designers | Table and Database Designers > uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
create table test (id int not null)
insert test values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
insert test values (null) -- fails
alter table test alter column id int null
insert test values (null) -- succeeds
select * from test
```